# cannot install dependencies on deployed app of streamlit

Tags: streamlit, pygobject, pycairo

i have a code that works fine on localhost, but when i deployed the streamlit app and tried to run it, im getting this error:

Collecting PyGObject
Downloading PyGObject-3.44.1.tar.gz (720 kB)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 720.5/720.5 KB 375.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00[2023-06-19 15:43:54.211094]
Installing build dependencies: started
Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [45 lines of output]
Collecting setuptools
Downloading setuptools-67.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.1/1.1 MB 25.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting wheel
Downloading wheel-0.40.0-py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 64.5/64.5 KB 201.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting pycairo
Downloading pycairo-1.24.0.tar.gz (344 kB)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 344.9/344.9 KB 354.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing build dependencies: started
Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
Getting requirements to build wheel: started
Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
Installing backend dependencies: started
Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
Building wheels for collected packages: pycairo
Building wheel for pycairo (pyproject.toml): started
Building wheel for pycairo (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

```
    × Building wheel for pycairo (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
    │ exit code: 1
    ╰─> [12 lines of output]
        running bdist_wheel
        running build
        running build_py
        creating build
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/cairo
        copying cairo/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/cairo
        copying cairo/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/cairo
        copying cairo/py.typed -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/cairo
        running build_ext
        'pkg-config' not found.
        Command ['pkg-config', '--print-errors', '--exists', 'cairo >= 1.15.10']
        [end of output]
  
    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycairo
  Failed to build pycairo
  ERROR: Could not build wheels for pycairo, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

In simple words i can't install pygobject. and i can't understand why :/

I have tried install manimce, pycairo, vext and vext.gi and none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

Installation instructions for various operating systems are provided on the [PyGObject Getting Started](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) page.